# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: тире

Матери сказали, что ее сын-дезертир. Нужно ли тире между сын дезертир.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Можно поставить. А можно и не ставить... Зависит от интонации.

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106 :

> **§ 10.** Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте отсутствующей
> связки ставится тире, если подлежащее
> и сказуемое выражены существительными
> в форме именительного падежа...
>
> **Примечание.** Тире может не ставиться, если в письменной речи
> отражено произношение с логическим
> ударением на сказуемом: *Моя сестра
> учительница* (ср.: *Моя сестра —
> учительница* — ударение и на слове
> *сестра,* и на слове *учительница*).

Comment: Не нравится мне это примечание) И как в письменной речи может быть отражено произношение?

Comment: Там же всё сказано.

Моя сестра **учительница**.
Моя **сестра** — **учительница**.

Answer (score 3):

Да, тире необходимо. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится, при отсутствии связки ( в вашем случае отсутствует связка "есть", которая опускается в настоящем времени), если оба главных члена выражены существительным в именительным падеже.

Comment: Спасибо, я согласна с вами полностью. Я тоже так думала, но сомневалась

Answer (score 1):

Всё-таки здесь гораздо лучше с тире, чем без тире. Логическое ударение и на слове *сын*, и на слове *дезертир*.

Comment: Не обязательно. 

Пример из книги: "Полковник спешил сообщить матери, что её сын дезертир" (
https://books.google.ru/books?id=KE8XAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B5%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%22&dq=%22%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B5%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=_CnmVNrTMKv6ygOP3oDwBA&redir_esc=y
).

Comment: @slava1947, год издания книги смотрели? 2005 - в это время уже да-авно (лет пятнадцать как) было "всё позволено".

Comment: Что именно "всё"? И кем позволено? Правила не менялись

Comment: 1) не соблюдать правила (которые да, не менялись); 2) царём (отсутствующим в голове).

Answer (score 0):

У Розенталя описан такой случай: тире не ставится, если предложение разговорного стиля и простой конструкции, например: "Мой отец врач". Все точно так, как в Вашем предложении

Answer (score 0):

Без тире. Либо тире между пробелами.

Матери сказали, что ее сын - дезертир.

А в этом случае - без пробелов. 
Матери сказали, что ее сын-дезертир задержан.

Или: При виде матери сын-дезертир  опустил глаза.

Comment: Сын-дезертир пишется через дефис, а не через тире. "Дезертир" здесь приложение.

Comment: В приведенном примере "Матери сказали, что ее сын-дезертир", ''дезиртир'' не является приложением. А в предложении ''При виде матери сын-дезертир опустил глаза'', ''дезиртир'' действительно является приложением.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не тире, а дефис. Дефис здесь не подходит. Я ставлю длинное тире в ворде при помощи Ctrl + -

Есть очень хороший бесплатный текстовый редактор OpenOffice 4.1.1. Там дефис автоматически заменяется на тире в нужных случаях. Этот редактор намного лучше ворда. Нужно просто попробовать его в работе, и вы увидите в чем его преимущества. А вообще тире заменяет пропущенное слово **это**.

Матери сказали, что ее сын **это** дезертир. Поэтому тире здесь видимо нужно.

Comment: @Yuri Ochichenko, делать тире в Ворде, а потом копировать сюда, согласитесь - возня.  В Ворде иногда и без сочетания этих клавиш получается  тире ( длинное), а иногда не получается.  Здесь только дефис получается, поэтому приходится отделять пробелами.

Answer (score 0):

По правилам русского языка в большинстве случаев (а случаев очень много) тире ставится вместо отсутствующего слова. В рассматриваемом предложении отсутствует глагол быть в форме настоящего времени, то есть есть. А Розенталь, как и мы, имеет право иметь собственное мнение.

Comment: А ссылка у вас есть на те самые "правила русского языка", которым противоречит "собственное мнение" Розенталя?

Это мы тут имеем право излагать "собственное мнение" без оглядки на что бы то ни было. Учёный такого права практически лишен.

Answer (score 0):

Niemand, Розенталь не нарушил здесь правило, поскольку правила здесь нет. А есть обычай, что он и отразил в начале полной фразы об отце враче: "Тире обычно не ставится, если предложение...". Во французском , немецком языках в подобных предложениях сохранилось обязательное "есть" (est, ist); русские  отказались от этой связки, заменив ее на письме знаком тире, а затем перестали ставить и тире, что вошло в обычай. А это уже стало нарушением правила, приведенного в параграфе 10 у slava 1947.